# About Terminal Problem

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have recently joined Ubuntu version 16.04. When i open the terminal it displays this message "**To run a command as administrator(user "root"), use sudo command** ". Please help me with this problem asap.

It happened to me (@waltinator), too. I did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> to open a teminal, and is my wont, did 3 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> to open additional teminal screens. The additional screens got the message:

```
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.
```

before my `.bashrc` finished.

I can't find anywhere in my `.bashrc` or its `include`d files where I attempt to `sudo` anything (sounds like a Bad Idea) during my login process. I do set up aliases that `sudo` when evaluated, but not when defining the alias:

```
$ egrep 'sudo |su ' .bashrc .bash_aliases /etc/profile.d/color_ls.sh etc/bash_path_funcs/* 
.bashrc:# makes "sudo" easier: sudo less $LESS files
.bash_aliases:alias bigopenfiles="sudo lsof / | awk '{if(\$7 > 1048576) print \$7/1048576 \"MB\" \" \" \$9 }' | sort -n -u" 
.bash_aliases:alias deletedfiles="sudo lsof / | egrep 'PID|\(deleted\)'"
.bash_aliases:alias bigopenfiles="sudo lsof / | awk '{if(\$7 > 1048576) print \$7/1048576 \"MB\" \" \" \$9 }' | sort -n -u" 
.bash_aliases:alias deletedfiles="sudo lsof / | egrep 'PID|\(deleted\)'"
.bash_aliases:alias aptfixkey="sudo gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys "
.bash_aliases:alias susp="sudo -v && sleep 20 && echo 'Zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz' && date && sudo pm-suspend && date && echo 'Awake'"
.bash_aliases:alias update='wupdatestatus=99;while [[ $wupdatestatus -ne 0 ]] ; do sudo apt-get update; wupdatestatus=$?;echo "status=$wupdatestatus";if [[ $wupdatestatus -ne 0 ]] ; then date; sleep 300; fi; done'
.bash_aliases:alias upgrade='wupgradestatus=99;while [[ $wupgradestatus -ne 0 ]] ; do sudo apt-get upgrade; wupgradestatus=$?;echo "status=$wupgradestatus"; if [[ $wupgradestatus -ne 0 ]] ; then date; sleep 300; fi; done'
.bash_aliases:alias upgradedl='wupgradestatus=99;while [[ $wupgradestatus -ne 0 ]] ; do sudo apt-get --download-only upgrade; wupgradestatus=$?;echo "status=$wupgradestatus"; if [[ $wupgradestatus -ne 0 ]] ; then date; sleep 300; fi; done'
.bash_aliases:alias dist-upgrade='wupgradestatus=99;while [[ $wupgradestatus -ne 0 ]] ; do sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; wupgradestatus=$?;echo "status=$wupgradestatus"; if [[ $wupgradestatus -ne 0 ]] ; then date; sleep 300; fi; done'
.bash_aliases:alias wup='wifi;sudo rmmod rt2800usb;sudo modprobe rt2800usb;nmcli con up id Nick;wifi;ping3 slashdot.org'
.bash_aliases:    sudo tail -n 50 $( ls -rt1 /var/log |sed -e 's%^%/var/log/%'| tail -n 6 )
grep: /etc/profile.d/color_ls.sh: No such file or directory
```

None of the logs help:

```
$ sudo grep -l sudo /var/log/* /var/log/*/* 2>/dev/null
```

shows nothing interesting.

How do I track down who/what is trying to `sudo` when I login?

Comment: What problem, exactly? it's just an informational message

Comment: But my terminal opens just for a instance(hardly for 10 secs). Now, What should I do??????????

Comment: Does `xterm` (opened from the Ubuntu dash, or the run dialog) behave in the same way? If yes, the problem is probably in your shell (such as a bad .bashrc file); if not, it's more likely a problem with the gnome-terminal itself (such as a bad entry in the "custom command" field).

Answer (score 3):

This is just an informational message telling you that in case you want to run a command with root user privileges, you have to use `sudo`.

Once you ran your first `sudo` command, this information will no longer appear.

If you don't know what `sudo` or "root user privileges" are, you probably don't need that at all yet. In case you're still curious, you might start reading about it [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) though.

To get rid of the message, simply run a `sudo` command like this:

```
sudo echo "Hello world"
```

It will ask you for your account password and then print the string "Hello world" to the terminal as root - which has no real use, but is enough for this case.