# can't pass sudo password

Tags: command-line, 16.04, sudo

I can't do anything. Whenever I use "sudo", I receive "sorry, try again". I need to install gcc. Can anyone help me?

[image: screenshot]

```
To run a command as administrator (user "root") use root "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

zyl@zyl-HP-348-G4:~$ sudo apt install gcc
[sudo] password for zyl: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for zyl: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for zyl: 
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
zyl@zyl-HP-348-G4:~$
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [About Terminal Problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/808928/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could type the `sudo` password slowly, and be attentive on what you are typing. This could help. Or change the password if you still can't.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.

Comment: @ZayarLinn I'm glad it's solved. From your comment, my understanding is that you were either able to type the password correctly, or you were able to fix the problem by resetting the password described in the other answer. However, if that is not the case and [the question we've closed this as a duplicate of](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) doesn't solve it, then it can be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

Hold shift at start up to open grub, then move down to the option with your Linux distro, followed by **(Recovery Mode)**

You want click the down arrow until you hover over root, then click enter.

Next U’ll see command line with the text

```
root@ubuntu:~#
```

You then want to remount with permissions by doing the following command

```
mount -o remount, rw /
```

Now all you have to do is

```
passwd username
```

Replace username with whatever your username is, then enter your new password